# Get single value from XML and bind it to a textblock?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Trying to create a prayer time app for prayertimes in Oslo. I have a XML file located in the app.
What i want to do:
Based on month and the day, get value for morning prayer, evening prayer and so on.

I want one value at a time, and show it in a textblock. how do i do it?
I am currently getting the info in a listBox but i rather want the single value to be shown in a textblock. Or should i use some other thing?

```
public class PrayerTime
 {   
   public string Fajr { get; set; }
   public string Sunrise { get; set; }

}
```

To get the value:

```
XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load("WimPrayerTime.xml");
var filteredData = from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("PrayerTime")
       where c.Attribute("Day").Value == myDay.Day.ToString()
       && c.Attribute("Moth").Value == myDay.Month.ToString()

        select new PrayerTime()
            {
                Fajr = c.Attribute("Fajr").Value,
                 Soloppgang = c.Attribute("Soloppgang").Value,
             };
listBox1.ItemsSource = filteredData;
```

Also i want to know how best the XML should be set up for this purpose.

Like this:

```
<PrayerTime>
<Day>1</Day>
<Month>5</Month>
<Fajr>07:00</Fajr>
<Sunrise>09:00</Sunrise>
</PrayerTime>
```

Or like this:

```
<PrayerTime
Day ="1" 
Month="5" 
Fajr="07:00" 
Sunrise="09:00" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 yourTextBox.Text = filteredData.First().Fajr;
```

As to know whether it's best to put information in a XML file as attributes or nodes, that's a recurrent question with no definite answer. In most cases, it's just a matter of taste.